# In C programming, where is a variable stored if it is declared as a global variable but is then malloced in main?

Tags: c, memory

I know that global variables are stored in static data and things that use malloc are stored on the heap. This case seems like a contradiction. Where would it be stored?

ex:

```
char* example;

int main(){
    example = malloc(1);
}
```

edit: thanks everyone, I think I understand now!

Comment: Please show some code to illustrate what you mean. A variable itself is not malloced. What you probably mean is declaring a pointer and then mallocing some memory with the memory address assigned to the pointer. In this case the pointer variable is not being allocated but rather the thing it points to is.

Comment: What exactly does `declared as global but malloced in main` even mean?

Comment: @AlexBaur given that you seem to have clarified your doubts, if any of the answers helped you doing so, you should act according to the [help guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

There is no contradiction.

Variables defined at file scope typically live in the data area of the program, while dynamically allocated memory lives in the heap.  In your example, the variable `example` lives in the data segment, while the memory it points to (after the call to `malloc`) lives on the heap.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a global variable in a C program, it is indeed stored in the data segment of the process when executed. Now given your example you would have something like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *num; // or int *num = NULL;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  num = malloc(sizeof(int));
  *num = 10;
  return 0;
}
```

In this example what exists in the data segment is space reserved by the compiler for an int * called num. When malloc is executed then memory from the heap is indeed reserved for an int, and the address of that memory is returned and stored in the num.

Thus num does live in the data segment but the actual data, 10 in this case is stored on the address pointed by num, which is located in the heap.
I tried my best to explain it as clear as I could, but feel free to ask for any clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct really_big_data {
  char data[2000];
  size_t used;
};

struct really_big_data
    global_data; /* all space allocated in program static at program startup */
struct really_big_data
    *global_ptr; /* space for one pointer in program static */

int main() {
  global_ptr = calloc(1, sizeof *global_ptr); /* space on heap allocated at runtime */

  free(global_ptr);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The space (probably 8 bytes or 4 bytes) for `address` is usually in the data segment of the executable file. The byte you allocated with `malloc` will be on the heap of the process.

There is no contradiction because "global" is more of a lexical consideration, not necessarily a space consideration as raised by your question. A variable with global scope (i.e, file scope) means any code block can reference it. Exceptions are if you have a locally scoped variable with the same name, in which case that block won't be able to address the globally scoped variable.